Blazor .Net 8 auto rendering and Mediatr
I have recently started a new Blazor web project with .net 8 and autorendering (SSR, Server and WebAssembly) and Clean Architecture.
For the moment, I'm still using the architecture of the original project (CRUD service and rendering-dependent implementation), but I would like to implement the Mediatr pattern in my solution.
If I implement this, I don't see how I can manage the rendering-dependent implementation.
I've tried to find the same subject on the net with no result.
Is it possible to implement a Mediatr pattern in Blazor 8 with AutoRendering without create intermediary service (
Thank you for your help.
I tried to implement Mediatr in my solution, but I lost the WebAssembly service injection.

Your question is too broad at the moment to be a good fit for Stack Overflow. If possible, show some code that demonstrates what the problem is.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
